# How to solve FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore problem?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am trying to set up Firebase with next.js. I am getting this error in the console.

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

This is one of my custom hook

```
import { onAuthStateChanged, User } from '@firebase/auth'
import { doc, onSnapshot, Unsubscribe } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { auth, fireStore } from './firebase'

export const useUserData = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string | null>(null)

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribe: void | Unsubscribe

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user)
        // The Problem is inside this try blog
        try {
          // the onsnapshot function is causing the problem
          console.log('firestore: ', fireStore)
          unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(fireStore, 'users', user.uid), (doc) => {
            setUsername(doc.data()?.username)
          })
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message)
        }
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null)
        setUsername(null)
      }
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [currentUser])

  return { currentUser, username }
}
```

I also have this firebase.ts file where I initialized my firebase app

```
import { FirebaseApp, getApps, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'some-api',
  authDomain: 'some-auth-domain',
  projectId: 'some-project-id',
  storageBucket: 'some-storage-bucket',
  messagingSenderId: 'some-id',
  appId: 'some-app-id',
  measurementId: 'some-measurement-id',
}

let firebaseApp: FirebaseApp

if (!getApps.length) {
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

const fireStore = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp)

export { fireStore, auth, storage }
```

I don't know whether the problem is in the project initialization. I am pretty sure the error is generated from my custom hook file. I also found out that there must be something wrong with `onSnapshot` function. Am I passing the docRef wrong or something? What am I doing wrong here?

The `console.log(firestore)` log:

```
    type: "firestore-lite"
    _app: FirebaseAppImpl
    _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false
    _config: {name: "[DEFAULT]", automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false}
    _container: ComponentContainer {name: "[DEFAULT]", providers: Map(15)}
    _isDeleted: false
    _name: "[DEFAULT]"
    _options:
    apiKey: 'some-api'
    authDomain: 'some-auth-domain'
    projectId: 'some-project-id'
    storageBucket: 'some-storage-bucket'
    messagingSenderId: 'some-id'
    appId: 'some-app-id'
    measurementId: 'some-measurement-id'
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    automaticDataCollectionEnabled: (...)
    config: (...)
    container: (...)
    isDeleted: (...)
    name: (...)
    options: (...)
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    _credentials: Q {auth: AuthInterop}
    _databaseId: H {projectId: "next-firebase-fireship", database: "(default)"}
    _persistenceKey: "(lite)"
    _settings: ee {host: "firestore.googleapis.com", ssl: true, credentials: undefined, ignoreUndefinedProperties: false, cacheSizeBytes: 41943040, …}
    _settingsFrozen: false
    app: (...)
    _initialized: (...)
    _terminated: (...)
```

Comment: Hmm... can you try `doc(fireStore, collection('users'), user.uid)`, with `collection` also being imported from `'firebase/firestore'`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, That actually gives a type error

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of logs? `console.log('firestore: ', fireStore)` What does this log? The error says `Expected first argument to collection()` even for `doc()` method atm.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I edited the question. Take a look

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using `getFirestore` from `lite` library will not work with `onSnapshot`. You are importing `getFirestore` from `lite` version:

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
```

Change the import to:

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
```

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/firestore-lite#api_features_not_supported_by_firestore_lite),

> The `onSnapshot` method and `DocumentChange`, `SnapshotListenerOptions`, `SnapshotMetadata`, `SnapshotOptions` and `Unsubscribe` objects are not included in `lite` version.

---

Another reason for this error to show up could be passing invalid first argument to `collection()` or `doc()` functions. They both take a Firestore instance as first argument.

```
// Ensure that "db" is defined and initialized
const db = getFirestore();
// console.log(db);

const colRef = collection(db, "collection_name");
```

Comment: The lite version is useful only if you don't need real time listeners and basic CRUD operation are suffiecient.

Comment: still not working in my codes. : (

Comment: : ) corrected error. I had combined codes of firebase "Web Version 9" and "Web Version 8"

Comment: works like charm :)

Answer (score 12):

#### Don't mix usage of `firestore/lite` with `firestore`

You need to use in your imports either:

```
'firebase/firestore'
```

OR

```
'firebase/firestore/lite'
```

Not both in the same project.

In your case, the `firebase.ts` file is using:

```js
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
```

And in your `hook`:

```js
import { doc, onSnapshot, Unsubscribe } from 'firebase/firestore'
```

So you're initialising the lite but using the full version afterwards.

Keep in mind that both has it's benefits, but I would suggest in your case to pick one and just use it. Then the error will be gone.

Comment: This was it for me. I thought I could use "lite" on some pages and not others.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Dharmaraj, if you are using firebase react hooks, use the reverse.

Instead of

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
```

Use

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using firebase lite then `collection` is not used.

Firebase lite example:

```
import {
 getFirestore,
 getDoc,
 updateDoc,
 doc
} from '@firebase/firestore/lite';

const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const docRef = doc(firestore, 'collection/doc');
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
await updateDoc(docRef, "field", 'value');
```

**When to use Firestore Lite**
It can be tricky to decide when to let go of the standard Firestore SDK's offline persistence and caching features. You should understand these features before deciding to trade them away for the lower overhead of Firestore Lite. In general, weigh these factors when deciding whether to use Firestore Lite:

1. **Online status** - Firestore Lite is good for apps that do not need live updates and have connectivity.
2. **Size constraints** - Firestore Lite is great if you want to reduce your overall JavaScript bundle size.

[Read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/firestore-lite)

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if you have both `@firebase/firestore` and `firebase` installed and there is a version mismatch.

`firebase` comes with `@firebase/firestore`. Remove any `@firebase/...` dependencies so that you're using the same version that `firebase` uses.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason as mentioned by other answers, yet there is one important part, as i was following old tutorial with next js 13 and firebase v9.

In my `firebase.tsx` the configuration file for firebase it self, was pointing to `/lite`

Changed this

```
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
```

To this

```
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```