# React Native: firestore/firebase Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference... how?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a simple React Native app that I created using Expo and debug on my personal Android device.

I've included firebase/firestore into my app and am now trying to add an object to firestore on button click.

Here's my code:

firebaseConfig.js :

```
import { initializeApp } from '@firebase/app';

var config = {
    ...
}
  
const app = initializeApp(config);

export default app;
```

Component:

import { app } from '../firebaseConfig';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { doc, setDoc, collection, query, where, getDocs, initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
...

export default function Component() {
const firestoreDb = getFirestore(app);

```
// this function is called when clicking a button
const onAddListPress = () => {
    setDoc(doc(firestoreDb, "cities", "LA"), {
        name: "Los Angeles",
        state: "CA",
        country: "USA"
    });
}
```

}

This throws the following error:

```
Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
```

This code above (in the onPress) is copied from the official firestore docs, here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Does anyone have an idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you edit your post and remove the `firebaseConfig` configuration keys, or delete your Firebase app and create a new one from the Firebase console to secure your app. I tried to replicate your application using React, and I received the same error message. There were two changes I made to correct the error. The first one is inside the `firebaseConfig file`, the default export needs to be changed to a named export:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

const firebaseConfig = {
    //Project configuration keys
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export { app }; // Change from a default to a named export
```

In addition, all the imports inside your component should come from the full Javascript SDK, not the lite version. The lite version has some [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/firestore-lite#api_features_not_supported_by_firestore_lite) which can result in this [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047904/) error.

```
import { app } from "./firestore-config";
import { getFirestore, getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const firestoreDB = getFirestore(app);
  const docRef = doc(firestoreDB, "users", "testUser1");

  const getData = async () => {
    const data = await getDoc(docRef);
    console.log(data);
  }

  getData();
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

You might also want to review this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5216) if you are using yarn to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Solved my issue as well, thanks