# in react.js collection() from firebase/firestore/lite works but from firebase/firestore doesn't

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In ReactJS I'm using firebase SDK v9.6.7
I managed to getDocs using the following code:

```
import {collection, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
const studentsCollection = collection(fbconfig.ProjectFirestore, 'students')
const studentsDocs = await getDocs(studentsCollection)
const studentsList = studentsDocs.docs.map(s => s.data())
```

As the lite package doesn't support snapshots, to query for a doc, I had to change my import to use the not-lite package and the code now looks as

```
import {collection, getDocs, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
const studentsCollection = collection(fbconfig.ProjectFirestore, 'students')
const studentsDocs = await getDocs(studentsCollection)
const studentsList = studentsDocs.docs.map(s => s.data())
```

Now the code is not working, and I have an error in react:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected first argument to
> collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or
> FirebaseFirestore

Anyhelp please?

Comment: The answer here helped me and solved the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889158/react-native-firestore-firebase-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a Thanks

Comment: Please post it also as your answer, so that other community members with the same issue can see your answer.  Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).