# Error when creating or overwriting a document in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying to add user or overwrite the user document in case the user already exists but I am getting this error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

What am I doing wrong?

```
import { auth, db }  from "../firebase"
import {doc, setDoc} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useEffect } from "react";


unction MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if(user){
      setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user?.uid), {
        email : user.email,
        lastSeen: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        photoURL : user.photoURL
      }, {merge: true});
    }
  }, [user])
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: How is `db` initialized and exported in your `firebase.js` file?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047904/how-to-solve-firebaseerror-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-coll

Comment: thanks have solve the issue, i was using firebase v8 to call the serverTimestamp() method

Answer (score 2):

i was using the firebase v8 to call the serverTimestamp() method
v8 module

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

v9 module

```
 serverTimestamp()
```