# Problem with onSnapshot Firebase - Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom pn object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use onSnapshot to get data from firebase but I am getting an error. Everything is working when I am using getDocs(), but with onSnapshot() there is a problem. Does anyone know what might be a problem?

**Firebase config**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
// hidden configuration
});
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
export default db;
```

**React code**

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState < DocumentData[] > ();

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, "todos"), (snapshot) => {
    setTodos(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        data: doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }))
    );
  });
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

**Error**

> FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom pn object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048162/13130697). `import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"` should work. The `lite` doesn't work with `onSnapshot()` Also, please add the `import` statement so we can see how you import `db` in this file.

Comment: That was actually a problem. Thanks !