# FirebaseError; Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Damnn really struggling with this one. I had to downgrade to firebase9.4.0 which allowed me to see where my code was throwing errors.

The error:
[image]

I have a separate file called queries.config.js which fetches all my necessary subcollections:

```
import { query, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebaseConfig";

const q1 = query(
    collection(db, "hairstyles/locs-hair-treatment/Locs Hair Treatment")
);
const q2 = query(
    collection(
        db,
        "hairstyles/locs-styles & protective-styles/Locs Styles & Protective Styles"
    )
);
const q3 = query(collection(db, "hairstyles/starter-locs/Starter Locs"));
const q4 = query(collection(db, "hairstyles/kids/Kids"));
const q5 = query(collection(db, "hairstyles/adults/Adults"));
const q6 = query(collection(db, "hairstyles/locs-package/Locs Package"));
const q7 = query(
    collection(db, "hairstyles/simple-locs-styles/Simple Locs Styles")
);
const q8 = query(
    collection(
        db,
        "hairstyles/natural-hair-and-external-care/Natural Hair & External Care"
    )
);
const q9 = query(collection(db, "hairstyles/silk-press/Silk Press"));
const q10 = query(collection(db, "hairstyles/colour-services/Colour Services"));

export { q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10 };
```

My firebaseConfig:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

console.log(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();

export { auth, db };
```

Comment: what if i deleted the firebase folder under ```node_modules```? Then reinstall firebase?

Comment: I'd typically just call `getFirestore()` in each file that needs it (i.e. `queries.config.js` here). But either way, I'd probably log `db` to see what its value is, if not one of the types that the API supports.

Comment: i ended up removing the ```queries.config.js``` file because nextjs had to full refreshes because of it to prevent issues (according to the log). when i logged ```db```, it return a ```ka``` object?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, in firebase 9.x the initialization methods (i.e getFirestore, getAuth, getStorage) receives one param -> a firebase app.

So your code is missing the following:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

I'm still convinced the solution is **passing the app as a parameter to getFirestore method**, to prove it **here I created a simple Next JS app where I fetch data from a collection using a query** too.

Im using `"firebase": "^9.17.2"`

**Firebase config file**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "some_api_key",
  authDomain: "some_auth_domain",
  projectId: "some_project_id",
  storageBucket: "some_storage_bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "some_messaging_sender",
  appId: "some_app_id"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const DB = getFirestore(app)

export default DB
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DB from "../core/firebase";
import { collection, query, getDocs, where } from "firebase/firestore";

function Header({ title }) {
  return <h1>{title ? title : "Default title"}</h1>;
} // this is a starter component from NextJS, ignore it.

export default function HomePage() {
  const [cases, setCases] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const renderList = cases.map((item, idx) => <div key={idx}>{item.topic}</div>);

  async function handleClick() {
    setLoading(true) // show loading text

    const q = query(
      collection(DB, "Cases"),
      where("email", "==", "john_doe@gmail.com")
    ); // create query using where as your example

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q); // getting docs passing the query we created

    const records = []; // here we will push our docs
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      records.push(doc.data());
    });

    setCases(records); // set our records in our state variables (cases)

    setLoading(false) // hide loading text
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      <Header title="Fetching firestore data " />
      <button style={{marginBottom: 10}} onClick={handleClick}>Fetch</button>
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {cases && renderList}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

I uploaded the code to github, you can check it out: [Github repository](https://github.com/David-Pena/quick-start-next-js)

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You should check if you have your full firebaseConfig inside your ENV file because I don't see anything wrong in your code. I have an exact version of that using classes and adding the app param inside getFirestore() its enough. After that, just reload the vscode in case there is some cache inside it.

I see you are missing this option "measurementId", but Im not sure if that one is mandatory.

Comment: Take a look at this post, its similar to yours and its also in NextJS. maybe there is some useful answers there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047904/how-to-solve-firebaseerror-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-coll

Comment: i added the ```databaseURL``` option to the config. I'm aware that it it's a url to the realtime database but i use cloud firestore so it's not mandatory. Error still persists

Comment: I just edited my answer and I added a code (and repository) I just developed a few moments ago using NextJS and following the same query structure you are trying to use, I hope its useful for you

Comment: ok so i tried your code and i get an error of: ```missing or insufficient permissions.```
i changed my firestore rules prior to this so i dont know why im getting the error.
My firestore rules ```rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The rule you have right now "request.auth != null" means that it won't let you consult any data unless you are authenticated (you execute any signIn method and have an active firebase session). Just for the exercise, edit the rule to this "allow read, write: if true". just to check if my code works for you

Comment: still getting the error. it makes no sense

Comment: Try to use the same firebase version as me in the example.

Comment: used the same version as you. no difference

Comment: Let me know if maybe you want us to connect through discord or something to take a look at it, it's so confusing why its not working for you

Comment: It's fine. i redid everything with a new firebase app and nexjs project. I also updated the firestore rules before hand. Everything works on the new project.

Comment: Nice to know, maybe you can give a check to my answer :)

Comment: I will definitely do that!