# Previous firebase query code no longer works, after npm audit fix

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Previous, my code looked like this and worked:

```
  async function getProjects(db, page = 0) {
    const q = getProjectQuery(page);
    const projectsSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    
    // const projectsSnapshot = await getDocs(
    //   query(
    //     collection(db, "projects"),
    //     where("userId", "==", user.id),
    //     orderBy("lastUpdated", "desc"),
    //   )
    // );
    const projectsList = projectsSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    setLastResult(projectsSnapshot.docs[projectsSnapshot.docs.length - 1]);
    ...
  }
```

The commented out section works now. However, I like my query builder function.

```
const getProjectQuery = (page) => {
    const pageSize = 10;
    const projectsRef = collection(db, "projects");
    if (type === "my-projects" && page === 0) {
      return query(
        projectsRef,
        where("userId", "==", user.id),
        orderBy("lastUpdated", "desc"),
        limit(pageSize)
        //startAt(pageSize * page)
      );
    } else if (type === "my-projects" && page !== 0) {
      return query(
        projectsRef,
        where("userId", "==", user.id),
        orderBy("lastUpdated", "desc"),
        limit(pageSize),
        startAt(lastResult)
      );
    } else if (type === "shared" && page === 0) {
      return query(
        projectsRef,
        where("hasAccess", "array-contains", user.id),
        orderBy("lastUpdated", "desc"),
        limit(pageSize)
        //startAt(pageSize * page)
      );
    } else if (type === "shared" && page !== 0) {
      return query(
        projectsRef,
        where("hasAccess", "array-contains", user.id),
        orderBy("lastUpdated", "desc"),
        limit(pageSize),
        startAt(lastResult)
      );
    }
  };
```

This code now results in the error message: `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Fn', but it was: a custom dh object.`

I'm inlined one example and it works... I don't understand what is causing my code not to work. And my attempts to roll back my `npm audit fix` have been unsuccessful. I just want my code to work again. Any suggestions about where to start?

In an attempt to figure this out, I also migrated from CRA, to Vite for my React app so that I could reduce all the audit warnings, because I assumed they mattered. The App runs, but fails at most firebase queries.

I've uninstall and reinstalled firebase, restarted my dev sever and emulators, restarted my computer etc. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fundamentally an issues with using both the lite and normal imports for firebase. After switching them all to "firebase/firestore" - everything is working normally again.

[How to solve FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047904/how-to-solve-firebaseerror-expected-first-argument-to-collection-to-be-a-coll)